# Javascript get date from class and add an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I wanted a way to have Javascript look through my HTML for hidden dates with a certain class, parse the date and check if it is greater than today's date. If that is true add an image to the parent element. It looks like it works but is this the best way to write the code?

```
$(".myClass").each(function() {
    var u = Date.parse($(this).text());
    var v = [u.valueOf()];
    var t = new Date();
    var d = Date.parse(t)

    if (v[0]>d)
    {
        $($(this).parent()).append("<img src='css/img/new.png' alt='icon' title='New Document' class='documentIconText' />");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "better" way, but you could cache the `$(this)` object into a variable. It would also help to have more descriptive variable names (`var currentDate`). This might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

You could cache the image. All the variables withing `each` don't seem necessary. This is another way to write your code:

```
var imgnew = $('<image/>')
             .attr({src: 'css/img/new.png', alt:'icon',
                    title: 'New Document', class: 'documentIconText'});

$(".myClass").each(function() {
  if ((Date.parse($(this).text()) || new Date()).getTime() > new Date) {
    $($(this).parent()).append(imgnew);
  }
});
```

**Note**: `(Date.parse($(this).text()) || new Date()).getTime()` ensures there is always a value to compare to